# Audio too high, how to troubleshoot

Tags: repeater, transceiver, audio

I am using a TYT TH-9800 with a 10 m half dipole antenna on low power (5 W) to connect to a WIN linked repeater (+5.0 MHz offset and 123.0 tone).

I made contact with two other stations and was told that "my audio was overloading and cutting out parts of my signal" and "my audio was high".

How should I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Floyd. If you find that one of the answers you receives solves your problem, please click the check mark below the answer so it gets marked by the system as "answered."

Answer (score 2):

Hold the HT/mic farther from your mouth and speak in a normal voice. I made this mistake when I first started using an HT. You *must not* "close talk" the mic the way you might have done with a handheld mic in the "olde days."

Comment: That was my first impulse, too, but reading the TH-9800 manual online, they recommend 2.5 – 5 cm distance. That's as close as it'll get to swallowing a mic.

Comment: One to two inches?  That's not "swallowing the mic", that's further than you'd hold a phone handset.

Comment: Many of us became accustomed to our lips brushing the mic when we spoke. One to two inches spacing can make a surprisingly big difference.